# randomly select 5 rows in c

Tags: c

I want to be able to randomly select 5 rows in C

Thanks.

Comment: This is far from a [mcve] because most of the code is unrelated to the question and you failed to say what is the output (or the errors) in it. Anyway, a simple way would be to randomly select 5 songs having an individual duration < 500, and then only keep from them the firsts for which the sum or duration is < 500.

Comment: What do you mean with "random"? Should all songs have the same probability (even though smaller songs are easier to fit in)?

Answer (score 0):

Let's think aloud a bit.

If you just need to select 5 arbitrary numbers that happen to sum up to a number below a given *N*, you can cheat and select just the 5 smallest numbers; if they sum up to a number larger than *N*,choosing any other numbers won't help, too, and you register an error.

If you want your numbers to sum up quite close to *N* (the user asked 20 minutes, you try to offer something like 19 minutes and not 5), it becomes a knapsack problem, which is hard, but maybe various approximate ways to solve it could help.

If you just want to choose 5 random numbers that sum up to *N*, you can keep choosing 5 numbers (songs) randomly and check. You'll have to limit the number of tries done and/or time spent, and be ready to report a failure.

A somehow more efficient algorithm would keep a list of songs chosen so far, and the sum of their lengths *s*. It would try to add to it a random song with length ≤ *N* - *s*. If it failed after a few attempts, it would remove the longest song from the list and repeat. It must be ready to admit failure, too, based on the total number of attempts made and/or time spent.

I don't think a simple SQL query could efficiently solve this problem. You can approximately encode the algorithm above as a very complex SQL query, though. I'd rather encode it in Python, because local SQLite lookups are pretty fast, provided that your songs are indexed by length.

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution is to only select songs for which the individual length is < 500. Then you keep as much of them as you can. If you have less than 5 or if the total time is < 500, then you iterate or recurse for find some songs for the unused time.

```
def createtimeplay(timee, tot = None, tot_time = 0):
    if tot is None: tot= []  # at first call initialize the result list
    # exclude previously selected songs from the search
    qry = "SELECT * FROM songs WHERE length <= ?"
    if len(tot) > 0:
        qry += " and name not in (" + ','.join(['?'] * len(tot)) + ')'
    qry += " ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 5 "
    curs = c.execute(qry, [timee] + [song[0] for song in tot])
    cur = (curs.fetchall())
    if len(cur) == 0: return tot   # no song were found: we can return
    # keep songs that fit in allowed time
    cur_time = 0
    for song in cur:
        if cur_time + song[1] <= timee:
            cur_time += song[1]
            tot.append(song)
            if (len(tot) == 5) return tot  # never more than 5 songs
    tot_time += cur_time                           # total songs time
    if len(tot) != 5 and cur_time != timee:        # if not all recurse
        createtimeplay(timee - tot_time, tot, tot_time)
    return tot
```

The trick is that we pass a list which is a modifiable object, so all recursive calls add songs to the same list.

You can then use:

```
>>> print(createtimeplay(500))
[('Song 18', 350, 'Country', 'z'), ('Song 4', 150, 'Pop', 'x')]
>>> print(createtimeplay(500))
[('Song 12', 200, 'Country', 'z'), ('Song 3', 100, 'Country', 'z'), ('Song 14', 200, 'Rap', 'y')]
>>> print(createtimeplay(500))
[('Song 5', 300, 'Rap', 'y'), ('Song 7', 200, 'Pop', 'x')]
>>>
```

---

But previous solution is very inefficient: it requires more than one query, when each query is a full table scan because of the *order by random()*, and uses recursion when it could easily be avoided. It would be both simpler and more efficient to only do a full table scan at sqlite level, shuffle the result in sqlite or Python, and then just scan once the full randomized list of songs, keeping a maximum number of 5  with a constraint of the total length.

Code is now much simpler:

```
def createtimeplay(tim, n, con):
    songs = c.execute("""SELECT name, length, genre, artist
        FROM songs
        WHERE length < ? ORDER BY RANDOM()""", (tim,)).fetchall()
    result = []
    tot = 0
    for song in songs:
        if song[1] <= tim:
            tim -= song[1]
            result.append(song)
            if len(result) == n or tim == 0: break
    return result
```

In this code, I choosed to pass the maximum number and a cursor or a connection to the sqlite database as parameters.